# How I can remove autoincrement from a Primary key in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment

In my postgresql I have the `values` table generated from this sql:

```
CREATE TABLE public.values (
    id int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('my_rable_seq'::regclass),
    value varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT values_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Or from this SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE public.values (
    id SERIAL,
    value varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT values_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And I do not want the autoincrement feature any more. How I can alter the table without removing-affecting any data?

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the default value on column and the corresponding sequence

```
alter table values alter column id drop default ;
drop sequence values_id_seq ;
```

Comment: Before dropping the sequence, we need to check if it is used elsewhere. It's not common but certainly possible for a sequence to be used by 2 or more columns in different tables.

Comment: How I do that @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Comment: Well, one hacky way would be to run the `drop sequence` and see the error message. If it succeeds, fine, there was no dependency. If it fails, you'll get an error like `ERROR:  cannot drop sequence values_id_seq because other objects depend on it  
DETAIL:  default value for column <column_name> of table <table_name> depends on sequence values_id_seq`

Comment: There is surely a way to find dependencies in advance by querying the system catalog (I'd have to check exactly how)